# Vertical scroll in overlay creating using angular-cdk

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5, angular-cdk

I've used cdk's Overlay to show some content when a button is clicked. Everything working as expected except the vertical scroll mechanism.

Content inside the overlay is getting the vertical scrollbar when I'm reducing the height of the browser. Given `max-height: 600px` and `height: 600px` to both `panelClass` and content too. But still the same behaviour.

Tried to look into angular-material dialog code but unable to understand how scrolling is achieved.

Due to lack of clear documentation on `Overlay.scrollStrategies` i'm not clear If I have to look in this direction.

Below is code extract, which I'm using for making the Overlay.

```
.help-menu-overlay-panel-class {
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    max-height: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.help-overlay-container {
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 600px;
}



<button [helpMenuOverlayTrigger]="helpMenuOverlayTemplate"></button>


<ng-template #helpMenuOverlayTemplate>
    <div class="help-overlay-container">
        ...
    </div>
</ng-template>



const overlayConfig: OverlayConfig = new OverlayConfig(<OverlayConfig>{
        hasBackdrop: true,
        direction: this.dir.value,
        backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop',
        maxHeight: '600px',
        maxWidth: '400px',
        panelClass: ['help-menu-overlay-panel-class']
    });

overlayConfig.positionStrategy = this.overlay
    .position()
    .connectedTo(
        this.elementRef,
        {
            originX: 'start',
            originY: 'bottom'
        },
        {
            overlayX: 'start',
            overlayY: 'top'
        }
    )
    .withOffsetY(10)
    .withOffsetX(-4)
    .withDirection(this.dir.value);

// overlayConfig.scrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition();

this._overlayRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);

this._overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(
    () => {
        this._overlayRef.detach();
    }
);
```

Comment: I think I got the solution that I need to set height something like `max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);`

Comment: You can add your comment as your answer and accept it 